# Diffrence between Coded UI Test with QTP, Selenium?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Why should i go for Coded UI, instead of QTP, Selenium. What is the difference between them. When to go Coded UI and when to QTP, Selenum. which is the good in market.

Comment: The choice is for Job search or to solve some technical challenge at work? Also, in the title you asked CodedUI *WITH* qtp? AFAIK Both dont go together.

Comment: Thank you for reply inquisitive, what i suppose to say is difference between coded ui , qtp.

Comment: my intension is to know, alredy QTP and selenum there, why Coded UI? why should i go for coded UI

Answer (score 0):

Should you want to test a suite which includes Windows Forms and XAML based applications, CodedUI will do those as well a browser based applications.